# how to sample a very big CSV file(6GB)

Tags: python, file, memory

There is a big CSV file (with first line as header), now I want to sample it in 100 pieces (`line_num%100` for example), how to do that efficiently with main memory constraint?

separate the file into 100 smaller one.Or every 1/100th line as sub file 1, every 2/100th line as sub file 2,...,every 100/100th line as file 100.
to get 100 files with size about 600 M.

Not get 100 lines or a 1/100 size's sample.

I tried to execute like this:

```
fi  = [open('split_data//%d.csv'%i,'w') for i in range(100)]
i = 0
with open('data//train.csv') as fin:
    first = fin.readline()
    for line in fin:
        fi[i%100].write(line)
        i = i + 1
for i in range(100):
    fi[i].close()
```

But the file is too big to run it with limited memory, how to deal with it?
I want to make it with one round~

(My code works but it consumes too much time and i mistakenly thought it collapsed, sorry for that~~)

Comment: Do you only want to read every 1/100th line?

Comment: I've updated my answer (in case you haven't looked at it in a while.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To split a file into 100 parts as stated in comments (*I want to split the file to 100 parts in modulus'ing way i.e. range(200)-->| [0,100]; [1,101]; [2,102]* and *Yes, separate a big one to hundreds of smaller files*)

```
import csv

files = [open('part_{}'.format(n), 'wb') for n in xrange(100)]
csvouts = [csv.writer(f) for f in files]
with open('yourcsv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    next(csvin, None) # Skip header
    for rowno, row in enumerate(csvin):
        csvouts[rowno % 100].writerow(row)

for f in files:
    f.close()
```

---

You can `islice` over the file with a step instead of modulus'ing the line number, eg:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('yourcsv') as fin:
    csvin = csv.reader(fin)
    # Skip header, and then return every 100th until file ends
    for line in islice(csvin, 1, None, 100):
        # do something with line
```

Example:

```
r = xrange(1000)
res = list(islice(r, 1, None, 100))
# [1, 101, 201, 301, 401, 501, 601, 701, 801, 901]
```

Comment: so if I want to get one hundred samples, it need to run a bigger loop like this 
`for i in range(100)
#your code with different index in islice#
`
?So I have to access the file one hundred times?

Comment: @ling sorry - I'm don't understand - could you elaborate?

Comment: @ling are you saying you want 100 rows (in total) from the entire file?

Comment: I want to split the file to 100 parts in modulus'ing way
i.e.
range(200)-->|
[0,100];
[1,101];
[2,102];
...

Comment: @ling ahh... well, I wouldn't have called that sampling and it's kind of a different question than the one it looks like you asked. So when you say "split the file" - is that to separate files or...?

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my first language, so i can't use it proficiently.

Comment: @ Yes, separate a big one to hundreds of smaller files~~

Comment: @ling what version of Python are you using?

Comment: my python version is 2.7.6

Comment: @ling updated answer to include an example of doing that... that does use modulus, but does require holding 100 open files at the same time to be able to get the splitting pattern you require

Comment: I'm running the code you given now, it performs well in memory consumption . Thank you very much!

Comment: @ling ahh good - I assume you remembered to open the files in write mode, I've updated the post for future visitors to reflect that :)

Comment: Your code works and the job is done, thanks. Can you explain it why my code doesn't works, but your codes perform well without remarkable memory usage in your answer?

Comment: @ling the code in your question appears to be very similar - I can't see anything that would cause any issues there...

Comment: it took too much time, so i mistakely believed it not works. I think i should edit the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @ling I'm guessing that your code was working, but you interrupted it, then ran mine, but your OS still had portions of the file cached - so it *appeared* to run faster because less physical disk access was required

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jon Clements answer, I would also benchmark this variation:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('in.csv') as fin:
  first = fin.readline() # discard the header
  csvin = csv.reader( islice(fin, None, None, 100) )  # this line is the only difference
  for row in csvin:
    print row # do something with row
```

If you only want 100 samples, you can use this idea which just makes 100 reads at equally spaced locations within the file. This should work well for CSV files whose line lengths are essentially uniform.

```
def sample100(path):
  with open(path) as fin:
    end = os.fstat(fin.fileno()).st_size
    fin.readline()              # skip the first line
    start = fin.tell()
    step = (end - start) / 100
    offset = start
    while offset < end:
      fin.seek(offset)
      fin.readline()            # this might not be a complete line
      if fin.tell() < end:
        yield fin.readline()    # this is a complete non-empty line
      else:
        break                   # not really necessary...
      offset = offset + step

for row in csv.reader( sample100('in.csv') ):
  # do something with row
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just open the same file 10 times and then manipulate (read) each one independently effectively splitting it up into sub-file without actually doing it.

Unfortunately this requires knowing in advance how many rows there are in the file and that requires reading the whole thing once to count them. On the other hand this should be relatively quick since no other processing takes place.

To illustrate and test this approach I created a simpler — only one item per row — and much smaller csv test file that looked something like this (the first line is the header row and not counted):

```
line_no
1
2
3
4
5
...
9995
9996
9997
9998
9999
10000
```

Here's the code and sample output:

```
from collections import deque
import csv

# count number of rows in csv file
# (this requires reading the whole file)
file_name = 'mycsvfile.csv'
with open(file_name, 'rb') as csv_file:
    for num_rows, _ in enumerate(csv.reader(csv_file)): pass
rows_per_section = num_rows // 10

print 'number of rows: {:,d}'.format(num_rows)
print 'rows per section: {:,d}'.format(rows_per_section)

csv_files = [open(file_name, 'rb') for _ in xrange(10)]
csv_readers = [csv.reader(f) for f in csv_files]
map(next, csv_readers)  # skip header

# position each file handle at its starting position in file
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(i * rows_per_section):
        try:
            next(csv_readers[i])
        except StopIteration:
            pass

# read rows from each of the sections
for i in xrange(rows_per_section):
    # elements are one row from each section
    rows = [next(r) for r in csv_readers]
    print rows  # show what was read

# clean up
for i in xrange(10):
    csv_files[i].close()
```

Output:

```
number of rows: 10,000
rows per section: 1,000
[['1'], ['1001'], ['2001'], ['3001'], ['4001'], ['5001'], ['6001'], ['7001'], ['8001'], ['9001']]
[['2'], ['1002'], ['2002'], ['3002'], ['4002'], ['5002'], ['6002'], ['7002'], ['8002'], ['9002']]
...
[['998'], ['1998'], ['2998'], ['3998'], ['4998'], ['5998'], ['6998'], ['7998'], ['8998'], ['9998']]
[['999'], ['1999'], ['2999'], ['3999'], ['4999'], ['5999'], ['6999'], ['7999'], ['8999'], ['9999']]
[['1000'], ['2000'], ['3000'], ['4000'], ['5000'], ['6000'], ['7000'], ['8000'], ['9000'], ['10000']]
```